Convergence of distribution sequence
Let $\{\phi_n\}$ a sequence of mollifiers in $\mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that the distribution $T_{\phi_n}$ associated, i.e., $$T_{\phi_n}(\Phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n(x)\Phi(x)dx,$$ converges to the Delta distribution, for every $\Phi$ test function. My textbook does the following $$T_{\phi_n}(\Phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n(x)\Phi(x)dx=\Phi(0)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n(x)(\Phi(x)-\Phi(0))dx\\=\phi(0)+kn\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}\exp(-1/(1-|nx|^2)(\Phi(x)-\Phi(0)),$$ and from here the convergence is easy to derive, but i don't understand this step, and the book does not provide any extra information. Is that every mollifier sequence has the form of such exponential? Thanks in advance!
EDITED: The book define mollifiers as a sequence of positive test functions such that $\operatorname{supp} (\phi_n)\subset \bar{B}(0,1/n)$ and such that $\|\phi_n\|_1=1.$

How does the book define mollifiers?

I edited it with the definition

The last part with the exponential is unnecessary and I'm pretty sure that it doesn't even define a mollifier in this form. I recommend ignoring it and just working with the $\phi_n$ and using the fact it's supported on $[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$.

Let's take the step
$$T_{\phi_n}(\Phi) = \Phi(0) + \int_{\mathbb R} \phi_n(x)(\Phi(x)-\Phi(0)) dx$$
as a starting point. Note that $\Phi$ is smooth on the compact set $\overline{B(0, \frac 1n)}$ and hence its derivative is bounded, meaning that $\Phi$ itself is Lipschitz continuous. Hence $|\Phi(x)-\Phi(0)|\le L |x|$ holds for every $x \in \mathbb R$. Now since $\mathrm{supp}(\phi_n) \subset \overline{B(0, \frac 1n)}$ we have using also the triangle inequality
$$\left \lvert \int_{\mathbb R} \phi_n(x) (\Phi(x)-\Phi(0)) dx \right\rvert \le\int_{B(0, \frac 1n)} \phi_n(x) |\Phi(x) - \Phi(0)| dx\le \int_{B(0,\frac 1n)} \phi_n(x) L|x| dx \le \frac Ln \int_{B(0, \frac 1n)}\phi_n(x) = \frac Ln.$$
Here we used the Lipschitz continuity of $\Phi$, the fact that we are integrating over $B(0, \frac 1n)$ and the assumption $||\phi_n||_1=1$.
Using this we have
$$|T_{\phi_n}(\Phi)-\Phi(0)| \le \frac Ln \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$ (note: $L$ does not depend on $n$, only on $\Phi$). In other words, the sequence $T_{\phi_n}(\Phi)$ converges to $\Phi(0) = \delta_0(\Phi)$ for every test function $\Phi$ which by definition of convergence of distributions (in the weak* sense) means $T_{\phi_n} \rightharpoonup^* \delta_0$.
